# Is sitting on a double-decker bus's upper deckmore hazardous than its lower deck?

Tags: everyday-life, popular-science

Some people have alleged that they feel more 'wobbly' or 'unstable' while seated on the upper deck, than on the lower.  Also, they allege that in a car crash accident, sitters on upper floors are more likely to be ejected out through the windshield.  Are these allegations true?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about safety.

Comment: To add to that automatically generated comment: hi LePressentiment, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! We don't address safety issues here, but if you edit your question to ask about a specific physics principle (think "why") in a way that makes it clear that it is not about personal safety, it can be reopened.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for the welcome! I've emended my question. Better? Please feel free to emend it; I know scarcely any physics.

Comment: Asking about the likelihood of being ejected seems not to be a physics question to me; you'd just need statistics on double-decker bus accidents to answer that. If you edit the question (including the title) to just ask whether the top floor wobbles more, and **why**, I think it would be all right.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks; I had always intended to ask about the reasons, not about statistics or probabilities. Have I distinguished this now? Please reopen?

Comment: Well, still I don't think it's really a _good_ question, because it doesn't ask about a particular physics concept, but it no longer seems so off topic that I feel the need to unilaterally force it to be on hold. So okay, I'll reopen it, but we'll see what the community thinks of it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about engineering and safety.  Also, physics is the same everywhere.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I've emended the question. Is it? I've tried to be more precise in my question title now.

Comment: No, the physics is the same on both the lower and upper deck. Your friends "wobble" is actually just the bus bouncing on the road. Since you are on the upper deck, you are further from the pivot (or should I say fulcrum) so you move further for each motion. Also, you are not likely to have any obstacles (bars or the driver) in front of you on the upper deck, so a sudden stop would put you up against the glass.

Comment: @LCD3: Thanks. What exactly does moving 'further for each motion' mean? Are you saying that the forces or other elements in physics affect upper deckers more? What does this imply?

Comment: If the bus hits a pothole 2" deep, the lower deck might move 1.5". The upper deck might move 3" due to the distance from where the bus pivots.